# Images are overlapping when resizing the page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, responsive-images

Hi stackoverflow community. I run into the issue when image elements (social media buttons) are running into the image on my webpage. First of all my elements are overflowing the div box where they are sat. I was trying to fix it with a `overflow`property, however it wasn't what I was after. So I tried to use `clearfix` to keep elements within the div and that just got out of control. So 2 hours later I still haven't solved the issue. I was trying to use `margin-right` to move social buttons away from the image, but it is not working. Also slightly out of this topic, after I have implemented social buttons with relative position my line at the top of the page got shorter in one end. Use to stretch almost across whole page and now it is cut. So, yeah two issues here. I would really appreciate some help. Here is my crucial for two problems code below:

HTML:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="top_page">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<ul id="nav_container">

<li><a href="about_proper.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="articles.html">Articles</a></li>
<li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
</div>
<div class="media_buttons">
<ul>
<li><a href="about_proper.html"><img src="social/facebook.png" alt="facebook_social_button" style="width:30px;height:30px;"/></a></li>
<li><a href="news.html"><img src="social/twitter.png" alt="twitter_social_button" style="width:30px;height:30px;"/></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<hr>
<h1>Travel locally and globally</h1>

<div class="content">
<img src="travel.jpg" alt="Go Travel" style="text-align:centre;width:504px;height:228px;"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #nav_container {

        margin: 0%;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 5px; 
        left:5px;
        right:5px;
        width:auto;

    }

    #nav_container li {
        display: inline;
        margin: 4%;
        font-family: Arial; 
    }

    #nav_container a {
        color:#3e3e3e;
        background-color:#ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;   
    }
    #nav_container a:hover {

        background-color:#ffffff;
        color: #3e5869;
    }

    #nav_container a:visited {
        color:#357c49;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    div {
        padding-top: 50px; 
        left:5px;
        right:5px;

    }

    h1 {
        text-align:center;
        margin: auto;
        width:60%;
        color: #73AD21;
        font-family: Arial;
        top:-40px;
        height: 6%;
        padding: 3%;
    }
    .content {
        margin:auto;
        text-align:center;
        top: 5px;
        padding-bottom:45px;
}
    .media_buttons {
        position:relative;
        top:300px;
        left:20%;
        border:solid;
        padding:5px;
        display:block;
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style-type:none;
    }

    .media_buttons li {
        list-style-type:none;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        margin-right:50px;
        float:left;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, just a little notice : `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` must be ine `<head>` not `<body>` , i'll check what i can do for you :)

Comment: So where exactly you want to put the social icons ?

Comment: Hi Mools, I want them to be along the image :)

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MoolsBytheway/smgqafcL/2/)

**EDIT**

```css
#nav_container {

        margin: 0%;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 5px; 
        left:5px;
        right:5px;
        width:auto;

    }

    #nav_container li {
        display: inline;
        margin: 4%;
        font-family: Arial; 
    }

    #nav_container a {
        color:#3e3e3e;
        background-color:#ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;   
    }
    #nav_container a:hover {

        background-color:#ffffff;
        color: #3e5869;
    }

    #nav_container a:visited {
        color:#357c49;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    div {
        padding-top: 50px; 
        left:5px;
        right:5px;

    }

    h1 {
        text-align:center;
        margin: auto;
        width:60%;
        color: #73AD21;
        font-family: Arial;
        top:-40px;
        height: 6%;
        padding: 3%;
    }
    .content {    
 margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    top: 5px;
    width: 596px;
    padding-bottom: 45px;
    position: relative;
}

    .media_buttons { 
     position: absolute;
    padding: 5px;
    display: block;
    top: 30px;
    width: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 1;
    list-style-type: none;

    }

    .media_buttons li {
     list-style-type: none;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;

    }
```

```html
<div class="top_page">
<ul id="nav_container">

<li><a href="about_proper.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="articles.html">Articles</a></li>
<li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
</div>

<hr>
<h1>Travel locally and globally</h1>

<div class="content">

<div class="media_buttons">
<ul>
<li><a href="about_proper.html"><img src="social/facebook.png" alt="facebook_social_button" style="width:30px;height:30px;"/></a></li>
<li><a href="news.html"><img src="social/twitter.png" alt="twitter_social_button" style="width:30px;height:30px;"/></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<img src="travel.jpg" alt="Go Travel" style="text-align:center;width:504px;height:228px;"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Mools, thank you for this, the thing is I want them along side the image and so it is not overlapping with that image when resizing the page.

Comment: you mean at the top left corner of the image ?

Comment: That's great. How did you manage to use just absolute positioning. I thought you only can move it inside a relatively positioned div?

Comment: you have to make it `absolute` so you can put it `on` the image instead of `relative` that will put it beside your picture , and then use `z-index:1` to make it's `z-index` greater than image's so the user can `click` it instead of clicking the picture

Comment: Hi Mols, when I implement the code I have the same issue as before. It is still overlapping. How do I make sure there is a lways a space between social buttons and the space when I resizing the page (making it smaller)?

Comment: can you post your code all page code in a jsFiddle, so i can see what's the problem, maybe some other css is causing the problem